# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

В джанге новичок поэтому прошу помощи от более опытных людей.

Это приложение frontend а-ля стартовая страница проекта, а класс это модель с ссылками на остальные приложения. То есть шапка сайта. От этого я жду рабочего результата. И оно скорее всего работает, но выдаёт исключение из заголовка моего вопроса.

```
from django.db import models

class LinksInHeader(models.Model):
    navigate = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    link_way = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.navigate

    def get_url(self):
        return '/frontend/%i' %self.link_way

'''
navigate = текст нашей ссылки в шапке
link_way = латиницей путь к приложению

__str__ = чтоб при выводе на страницу
ссылок из шапки название было кириллицей(opt.)
а путь к приложению был в get_url
get_url = путь до приложения
'''
```

вот frontend/view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from frontend.models import LinksInHeader
from django.views.generic import ListView


class HeaderLinks(ListView):
    model = LinksInHeader
```

вот frontend/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HeaderLinks, name='header' ),
]
```

А вот собственно и проблема, при переходе по 0.0.0.0:8000/frontend/
вы даёт ошибку. А из админки всё спокойно редактируется и сёрфится.

Вот трасировка

[image: traceback]

Надеюсь на вас. Ваши указание что мне с этим сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class-based views [надо преобразовать](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf) во view вызовом соответствующего [метода](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view):

```
url(r'^$', views.HeaderLinks.as_view(), name='header' ),
```